# Function is not correctly plotted + cosmetic questions d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I have two questions. I am trying to plot a function with d3.js. I have already come far, but I have two problems.

My code currently; https://jsfiddle.net/v0du66ey/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin  = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width   = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height  = 500 - margin.top  - margin.bottom,
    padding = 50;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  width  + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top  + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");    

var data = [];

for (var k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
    data.push({x: k, y: k});
}

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("linear");

    // Define x domain
    x.domain([-10, 10]);

    // Define y domain
    y.domain([-10, 10]);

    // Add x axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","x axis")
        .attr("transform","translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)

    // Add y axis 
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Add x grid
    svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class","grid")
        .attr("transform","translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis
            .tickSize(-height,-height,0)
            .tickFormat("")
        );

    // Add y grid
    svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class","grid")
        .call(yAxis
            .tickSize(-width,-width,0)
            .tickFormat("")
        );

    // Add x axis label  
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("font-size","15")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("x axis");

    // Add y axis label
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y",0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("font-size","15")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("y axis");

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d",line(data));

</script>
```

As you can see the function which I have defined, y = x. Is not correctly plotted along its entire domain. It goes for x from -10 to approx 2.5 and y from 10 to approx 7.5. What goes wrong here? I do not namely see it.

Furthermore I have a cosmetic question. I am trying to create a border around the whole plot on the axis and trying to get the ticks bars to point to the inside of the graph instead of outside. In other words, I want to have it more looking like, a Matlab plot, [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About cosmetic question: you need to set `innerTickSize()`, `outerTickSize()` and `tickPadding()` on your axises with a negative numbers.

About main question:
as far as you have scales you should set line's x and y data as a result of scale functions.

so your line code will look like this:

`var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .interpolate("linear");`

Here is jsfiddle with updated sample http://jsfiddle.net/n3Lndkum/

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much! Can you also tell me how to draw a black rectangle around the entire plot? Like the Matlab one?

Comment: If you want rectangle's sides to be axes - duplicate axes and set them appropriate translation.
Or just draw two lines on a top and right sides of your plot.

http://jsfiddle.net/n3Lndkum/1/ lines 57-60 and 69-72